# graph subgraph isomorphism with weighted vertexes

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, boost, isomorphism

Firstly i am a complete newbie in boost lib. There is boost graph library isomorphism program without weights.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/cxx11/all_of.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

using boost::make_iterator_range;
using boost::adaptors::transformed;
using boost::algorithm::all_of;

int main()
{
    typedef adjacency_list<setS, vecS, bidirectionalS> graph_type;
    int temp, networkSIZE, clusterSIZE;
    // Build graph1
    cout << "input cluster size" << endl;
    cin >> clusterSIZE;
    graph_type graph1(clusterSIZE);
    
    add_edge(0, 6, graph1); add_edge(0, 7, graph1);
    add_edge(1, 5, graph1); add_edge(1, 7, graph1);
    add_edge(2, 4, graph1); add_edge(2, 5, graph1); add_edge(2, 6, graph1);
    add_edge(3, 4, graph1);
    // Build graph2
    cout << "input network size" << endl;
    cin >> networkSIZE;
    graph_type graph2(networkSIZE);

    add_edge(0, 6, graph2); add_edge(0, 8, graph2);
    add_edge(1, 5, graph2); add_edge(1, 7, graph2);
    add_edge(2, 4, graph2); add_edge(2, 7, graph2); add_edge(2, 8, graph2);
    add_edge(3, 4, graph2); add_edge(3, 5, graph2); add_edge(3, 6, graph2);

    // Create callback to print mappings
    vf2_print_callback<graph_type, graph_type> callback(graph1, graph2);

    // Print out all subgraph isomorphism mappings between graph1 and graph2.
    // Vertices and edges are assumed to be always equivalent.
    bool found = vf2_subgraph_iso(graph1, graph2, callback);

    std::cout << "Found subgraph:" << std::boolalpha << found << std::endl;
}
```

How can i find subgraph ismomorphism with weighted vertexes(i mean maximum weighted subgraph) using boost library and can i do it at all using this library.
If no is there any library of any language where i can do it.
If no and there are no libraries. Can you please give me atleast complete implementation of Ullman or VF2 or Cordella or Bonicci algorithms because I cannot find an adequate and more or less compact and simple implementation of these algorithms. maybe i will modernise it with weights

I solved isomorphism task with weighted verteces and wrote a working program using simple c++, but I need a serious efficient algorithm

Comment: Your question does not appear to have direct relevance to Java programming, as the code that you've posted is not Java. I have taken the liberty of removing the tag, since there is no sense attracting those who follow this tag to your question.

Comment: "i mean maximum weighted subgraph" - what do you mean, exactly? " Ullman or VF2 or Cordella or Bonicci" - that's a lot of different algorithms. Can you describe which **specific** characteristics you require? Best with an example that shows what output you want to get, and what to avoid. In other words, make things specific. Don't just say "I wrote a working program" - show it, and tell us what is not to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on things.

To the best of my  knowledge it is **not** possible to cause `vf2_subgraph_iso` to consider vertices from the large graph in any preferential order. There is the `VertexOrderSmall` argument though in case you can leverage it to arrive at the best mapping(s) sooner.

So, what you can do is to generate multiple mappings. Just to show off some of the flexibilities, I decided to not only generate all mappings, but also render them as DOT renderings of a tree of (sub)graphs where the "root" graph contains all of the large graph, and the "child" graph contains just the mapped isomorphism with weigths, descriptors.

I assumed, for the sake of exposition that by "maximum weighted subgraph" you were referring to *edge weights*.

Without further ado:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e383795c6adf493)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::make_iterator_range;

// I cannot make up random weights well
#include <random>

// The things we do for pretty renderings...
#include <boost/graph/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>

namespace Dot { // lot of noise just to render pretty graphs
    using namespace boost;
    using Dict = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

    template <typename Base>
    using Wrap = adjacency_list<
        setS, vecS, bidirectionalS,
        property<vertex_attribute_t, Dict, typename vertex_property_type<Base>::type>, // vertex
        property<edge_index_t, int,
                 property<edge_attribute_t, Dict,
                          typename edge_property_type<Base>::type>>, // edge
        property<graph_name_t, std::string,                          // graph
                 property<graph_graph_attribute_t, Dict,
                          property<graph_vertex_attribute_t, Dict,
                                   property<graph_edge_attribute_t, Dict,
                                            typename graph_property_type<Base>::type>>>>>;
} // namespace Dot

static int s_dotfile_counter = 0;

template <typename Graph, typename Map>
static auto createRendering(Graph const& small, Graph const& large, Map correspondence) {
    using RenderTree = boost::subgraph<Dot::Wrap<Graph>>;
    using RV         = typename RenderTree::vertex_descriptor;

    // Render (sub)graph isomorphism map
    RenderTree root;
    auto& sub = root.create_subgraph();

    get_property(sub, boost::graph_name)  = "clusterSmall";
    get_property(root, boost::graph_name) = "large";

    // copy all of large graph into root
    auto ignore    = [&](auto...) {};
    auto copy_prop = [](auto tag, auto& src_graph, auto& tgt_graph) {
        return [&, tag](auto src_descr, auto tgt_descr) {
            put(tag, tgt_graph, tgt_descr, get(tag, src_graph, src_descr));
        };
    };

    std::vector<RV> copy_map(num_vertices(large));
    copy_graph(
        large, root,
        boost::vertex_copy(ignore)
            .edge_copy(copy_prop(boost::edge_weight, large, root))
            .orig_to_copy(make_iterator_property_map(copy_map.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, small))));

    // mark sub-graph vertices
    for (auto largev : make_iterator_range(vertices(large))) {
        auto small_v = get(correspondence, largev);
        auto root_v  = copy_map[largev];

        if (small_v != small.null_vertex()) {
            auto sub_v = add_vertex(root_v, sub);
            // auto sub_v = sub.global_to_local(root_v);

            std::ostringstream label;
            label << "{small:" << small_v << " | large:" << largev << "}";

            put(boost::vertex_attribute, sub, sub_v,
                Dot::Dict{
                    {"label", label.str()},
                    {"color", "green"},
                });
        } else {
            std::ostringstream label;
            label << "{large:" << largev << "}";

            put(boost::vertex_attribute, root, root_v,
                Dot::Dict{
                    {"label", label.str()},
                    {"color", "gray"},
                });
        }
    }

    double total_weight = 0;

    { // write .dot and render png, calculating total_weight
        std::string const fname = "dot" + std::to_string(++s_dotfile_counter);
        get_property(root, boost::graph_vertex_attribute)["shape"] = "Mrecord";

        for (auto e : make_iterator_range(edges(root))) {
            double w = get(boost::edge_weight, root, e);

            std::ostringstream label;
            label << "weight:" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << w;
            put(boost::edge_attribute, root, e, Dot::Dict{{"label", label.str()}});

            if (sub.find_edge(e).second)
                total_weight += w;
        }

        get_property(sub, boost::graph_graph_attribute) //
            ["label"] = "total weight: " + std::to_string(total_weight);

        {
            std::ofstream ofs(fname + ".dot");
            write_graphviz(ofs, root);
        }

        if (::system(("dot -Tpng '" + fname + ".dot' -o '" + fname + ".png'").c_str())) {
            std::cerr << "(couldn't not invokge graphviz dot tool)" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return total_weight;
}

int main() {
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<                 //
        boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, //
        boost::no_property,                              // vertex
        boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double>>;  // edge

    // Build smaller graph (graph1)
    Graph small, large;

    add_edge(0, 6, small);
    add_edge(0, 7, small);
    add_edge(1, 5, small);
    add_edge(1, 7, small);
    add_edge(2, 4, small);
    add_edge(2, 5, small);
    add_edge(2, 6, small);
    add_edge(3, 4, small);

    // Build larger graph (graph2)
    auto gen_weight = bind(std::uniform_real_distribution(0.1, 2.9), std::mt19937(42));
    add_edge(0, 6, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(0, 8, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(1, 5, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(1, 7, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(2, 4, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(2, 7, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(2, 8, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(3, 4, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(3, 5, gen_weight(), large);
    add_edge(3, 6, gen_weight(), large);

    // Create callback to print mappings
    using V = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    std::map<V, V> mapping;
    double best_weight = -INFINITY;

    auto callback = [&](auto f, auto f_inv) {
        auto w = createRendering(small, large, f_inv);
        std::cout << "found isomorphism mapping with total weight of " << w << "\n";

        if (w > best_weight) {
            best_weight = w;

            for (mapping.clear(); auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(small)))
                mapping.emplace(v, f[v]);
        }

        return true; // give us more isomorphisms if any
    };

    if (vf2_subgraph_iso(small, large, callback)) {
        std::cout << " best weight: " << best_weight << " mapping:";
        for (auto [s,l] : mapping)
            std::cout << " [" << s << ", " << l <<"]";
        std::cout << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "no isomorphisms\n";
    }
}
```

Prints, e.g.:

```
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 11.5698
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 11.5698
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 9.3165
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 9.3165
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 11.4182
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 11.4182
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 10.7861
found isomorphism mapping with total weight of 10.7861
 best weight: 11.5698 mapping: [0, 1] [1, 2] [2, 3] [3, 0] [4, 6] [5, 4] [6, 5] [7, 7]
```

> Note the pairs of equal weights are caused by the same vertex being omitted from the selection:

[image]

Those images were generated by `DOT` from graphviz files written like e.g. dot5.dot:

```
digraph large {
node [
shape=Mrecord];
subgraph clusterSmall {
graph [
label="total weight: 11.418200"];
0[color=green, label="{small:0 | large:0}"];
1[color=green, label="{small:3 | large:1}"];
2[color=green, label="{small:1 | large:2}"];
3[color=green, label="{small:2 | large:3}"];
4[color=green, label="{small:5 | large:4}"];
5[color=green, label="{small:4 | large:5}"];
6[color=green, label="{small:6 | large:6}"];
8[color=green, label="{small:7 | large:8}"];
2 -> 4[label="weight:1.35"];
3 -> 4[label="weight:1.03"];
1 -> 5[label="weight:2.28"];
3 -> 5[label="weight:0.50"];
0 -> 6[label="weight:2.33"];
3 -> 6[label="weight:1.92"];
0 -> 8[label="weight:0.61"];
2 -> 8[label="weight:1.39"];
}
7[color=gray, label="{large:7}"];
1 -> 7[label="weight:1.77"];
2 -> 7[label="weight:0.38"];
}
```

### UPDATE: Node Weights

To the comments, if you preferred node weights instead of edge weights, that's just simpler, because we don't have to figure out which edges belong in the isomorphism anymore:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c73fdd9674fe617)** (that's the version posted in the comment)

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2218e68a75db1e67)** Version further simplified (157 lines) and generalized:

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/vf2_sub_graph_iso.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using boost::make_iterator_range;

// I cannot make up random values well
#include <random>

// The things we do for pretty renderings...
#include <boost/graph/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/subgraph.hpp>

namespace Dot { // lot of noise just to render pretty graphs
    using namespace boost;
    using Dict = std::map<std::string, std::string>;

    template <typename Base>
    using Wrap = adjacency_list<
        setS, vecS, bidirectionalS, property<vertex_attribute_t, Dict>, // vertex
        property<edge_index_t, int, property<edge_attribute_t, Dict>>,  // edge
        property<graph_name_t, std::string,                             // graph
                 property<graph_graph_attribute_t, Dict,
                          property<graph_vertex_attribute_t, Dict, property<graph_edge_attribute_t, Dict>>>>>;
} // namespace Dot

static int s_dotfile_counter = 0;

template <typename Graph, typename Map, typename NodeWeight>
static auto createRendering(Graph const& small, Graph const& large, Map correspondence, NodeWeight nweight) {
    using RenderTree = boost::subgraph<Dot::Wrap<Graph>>;
    using RV         = typename RenderTree::vertex_descriptor;

    // Render (sub)graph isomorphism map
    RenderTree root;
    auto& sub = root.create_subgraph();

    get_property(sub, boost::graph_name)  = "clusterSmall";
    get_property(root, boost::graph_name) = "large";

    // copy all of large graph into root

    std::vector<RV> copy_map(num_vertices(large));
    static constexpr auto ignore = [](auto...) {};
    copy_graph(large, root,
               boost::vertex_copy(ignore).edge_copy(ignore).orig_to_copy(
                   make_iterator_property_map(copy_map.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, small))));

    // mark sub-graph vertices
    int total_weight = 0;

    for (auto largev : make_iterator_range(vertices(large))) {
        int  w       = get(nweight, largev);
        auto small_v = get(correspondence, largev);
        auto root_v  = copy_map[largev];

        std::ostringstream label;
        std::string        color;

        if (small_v != small.null_vertex()) {
            total_weight += w;
            /*auto sub_v =*/ add_vertex(root_v, sub);

            label << "{small:" << small_v << " | large:" << largev << "}";
            color = "green";
        } else {
            label << "{large:" << largev << "}";
            color = "gray";
        }

        label << "|weight:" << w;
        put(boost::vertex_attribute, root, root_v,
            Dot::Dict{
                {"label", label.str()},
                {"color", color},
            });
    }

    { // write .dot and render png
        std::string const fname = "dot" + std::to_string(++s_dotfile_counter);
        get_property(root, boost::graph_vertex_attribute)["shape"] = "Mrecord";

        get_property(sub, boost::graph_graph_attribute) //
            ["label"] = "total weight: " + std::to_string(total_weight);

        {
            std::ofstream ofs(fname + ".dot");
            write_graphviz(ofs, root);
        }

        if (::system(("dot -Tpng '" + fname + ".dot' -o '" + fname + ".png'").c_str()))
            std::cerr << "Couldn't not invokge graphviz dot tool" << std::endl;
    }

    return total_weight;
}

int main() {
    struct NodeProps { int processing_power; };
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, NodeProps>;

    // Build smaller graph (graph1)
    Graph small, large;

    add_edge(0, 6, small);
    add_edge(0, 7, small);
    add_edge(1, 5, small);
    add_edge(1, 7, small);
    add_edge(2, 4, small);
    add_edge(2, 5, small);
    add_edge(2, 6, small);
    add_edge(3, 4, small);

    // Build larger graph (graph2)
    auto gen_power = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution(30, 120), std::mt19937(std::random_device{}()));
    add_edge(0, 6, large);
    add_edge(0, 8, large);
    add_edge(1, 5, large);
    add_edge(1, 7, large);
    add_edge(2, 4, large);
    add_edge(2, 7, large);
    add_edge(2, 8, large);
    add_edge(3, 4, large);
    add_edge(3, 5, large);
    add_edge(3, 6, large);
    for (auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(large)))
        large[v].processing_power = gen_power();

    // Create callback to print mappings
    using V = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
    std::map<V, V> mapping;
    int best_power = INT_MIN;

    auto callback = [&](auto f, auto f_inv) {
        auto w = createRendering(small, large, f_inv, get(&NodeProps::processing_power, large));
        std::cout << "found isomorphism mapping with total weight of " << w << "\n";

        if (w > best_power) {
            best_power = w;

            for (mapping.clear(); auto v : make_iterator_range(vertices(small)))
                mapping.emplace(v, f[v]);
        }

        return true; // give us more isomorphisms if any
    };

    if (vf2_subgraph_iso(small, large, callback)) {
        std::cout << " best weight: " << best_power << " mapping:";
        for (auto [s,l] : mapping)
            std::cout << " [" << s << ", " << l <<"]";
        std::cout << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "no isomorphisms\n";
    }
}
```

With a sample run output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! i'll go try to understand something sorry for not answering your question. And there is little poblem. I would still want a vertex (node) weights. Because the task that im trying to solve is network(graph) with computers and each computer have efficiency(weight) and i need to create a cluster(subgraph) based on this network that has max efficiency. so if it isnt possible to bind a weight to node maybe possible to do not bidiretional edges but to do two edges with opposite directions between two connected nodes. I mean all edges directed to one node have the same weight. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you assume it’s “not possible to bind a weight to a node”? I never said that. Just … do that! It’ll be easier (because isomorphisms are mapping nodes, not edges explicitly). I just assumed edge weight because the question failed to specify it, and it is the more typical “weight” in my experience

Comment: Here is the example program adapted to use vertex weights instead of edge weights: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c73fdd9674fe617 Some outputs of several runs (now that the weights use a random seed) https://imgur.com/a/olzCRj2

Comment: I simplified and generalized that and updated the answer with it.

Comment: Thank you bro again! thats what i need. Im so gratefull. Hope i will understand all of this code.